# Unity AssetBundle.LoadAsync and Code Stripping

Tags: ios, optimization, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

We need to reduce the memory consumption of our title, initially for iOS and then later for Android.

One of the areas we're looking at is code stripping as suggested in the article [Optimizing the Size of the Built iOS Player](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html).

Testing the various stripping levels, assemblies and byte code, we are experiencing a crash at runtime. I have narrowed this down to using the `AssetBundle.LoadAsync()` method, replacing its usage with `AssetBundle.Load()` calls. Whilst this is has stopped the crash, it has severely broken parts of the game that at this late stage we don't have the time to repair.

So, taking a step back - the code stripping is removing a dependency of `AssetBundle.LoadAsync()` that causes the game to crash at runtime. In the [linked article](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html) it says to use a `link.xml` file to specify additional dependencies (I've  had to add `System.Security.Cryptography` to this list).

**Q:** What are the dependencies required for `AssetBundle.LoadAsync()`?

Also, are there any tips for working out dependencies? I had a peek in .NET Reflector however that didn't yield much information as it just calls an external DLL.

Comment: I will e-mail Unity Support directly (we have premium support) and update with the answer.